# in polylang pro in wordpress website url tranlation fix

Tags: wordpress, redirect, plugins, translation, polylang

my website name is gta5.ca
in this website i added the polylang plugin . i translated the website to all multiplate diffrent languages .

so, on translating the post in that post i have added downlaod link ( it translating that downalod link also

her is orriaganl link: **https://gta5mod.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/OpenIV_Package_Creator_102.zip**

main page link is https://gta5.ca/openiv/file/?urls=**https://gta5mod.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/OpenIV_Package_Creator_102.zip**&names=Download%20OpenIV%20Package%20Creator&sizes=3.1%20MB

but in translated page it auto adding language code ( ru ) link: https://ru.gta5.ca/%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-iv/file/?urls=**https://ru.gta5mod.net**/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/OpenIV_Package_Creator_102.zip&names=Download%20OpenIV%20Package%20Creator&sizes=3.1%20MB

**to fix : plaese tell me how i can do stop to translate this redirecting page url**
to make ity reamin orignal downlaod link